# CSS display: grid show second row from right to left

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using CSS-Grid.

```css
.checkers {
  --item-size: 12vw;
  --item-bg-color: #222;
  --item-txt-dark-color: #222;
  --item-txt-light-color: #fff;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, var(--item-size));
  grid-auto-rows: var(--item-size);
  place-content: center;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: var(--item-bg-color);
  color: var(--item-txt-light-color);
}


/* design styles */
.checkers {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.checkers__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkers">
  <div class="checkers__item">1</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">2</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">3</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">4</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">5</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">6</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">7</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">8</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">9</div>
</div>
```

Now I need the box is set like below:
[image]

Is it possible using this CSS grid?

Comment: Yes, it is you can either use `grid-template-areas`- or `order`-property to do it. Note, that you want to change the 2nd row not column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `order`-property to re-arrange the placement:

```css
.checkers {
  --item-size: 12vw;
  --item-bg-color: #222;
  --item-txt-dark-color: #222;
  --item-txt-light-color: #fff;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, var(--item-size));
  grid-auto-rows: var(--item-size);
  place-content: center;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: var(--item-bg-color);
  color: var(--item-txt-light-color);
}

/* reordering elements */
.checkers__item:nth-child(-n+3) {
  order: 1;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(4) {
  order: 4;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(5) {
  order: 3;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(6) {
  order: 2;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(n+7) {
  order: 5;
}


/* design styles */
.checkers {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.checkers__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkers">
  <div class="checkers__item">1</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">2</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">3</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">4</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">5</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">6</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">7</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">8</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">9</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use the `grid-template-areas`-property:

```css
.checkers {
  --item-size: 12vw;
  --item-bg-color: #222;
  --item-txt-dark-color: #222;
  --item-txt-light-color: #fff;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, var(--item-size));
  grid-auto-rows: var(--item-size);
  place-content: center;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "six five four"
    "seven eight nine";
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: var(--item-bg-color);
  color: var(--item-txt-light-color);
}

/* grid-areas */
.checkers__item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: two;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: three;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: four;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: five;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: six;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: seven;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-area: eight;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-area: nine;
}


/* design styles */
.checkers {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.checkers__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkers">
  <div class="checkers__item">1</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">2</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">3</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">4</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">5</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">6</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">7</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">8</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly edit the numbers in html, if only display needs to be like the shared picture.

```css
.checkers {
  --item-size: 12vw;
  --item-bg-color: #222;
  --item-txt-dark-color: #222;
  --item-txt-light-color: #fff;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, var(--item-size));
  grid-auto-rows: var(--item-size);
  place-content: center;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: var(--item-bg-color);
  color: var(--item-txt-light-color);
}


/* design styles */
.checkers {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.checkers__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkers">
  <div class="checkers__item">1</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">2</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">3</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">6</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">5</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">4</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">7</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">8</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a lot of code. Only

```css
.checkers__item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: 2/1; /* 2nd row, 1st column */
}
.checkers__item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 2/3; /* 2nd row, 3rd column */
}
```

Will do the job:

```css
.checkers {
  --item-size: 12vw;
  --item-bg-color: #222;
  --item-txt-dark-color: #222;
  --item-txt-light-color: #fff;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, var(--item-size));
  grid-auto-rows: var(--item-size);
  place-content: center;
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: var(--item-bg-color);
  color: var(--item-txt-light-color);
}

.checkers__item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: 2/1;
}
.checkers__item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 2/3;
}


/* design styles */
.checkers {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.checkers__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkers">
  <div class="checkers__item">1</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">2</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">3</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">4</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">5</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">6</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">7</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">8</div>
  <div class="checkers__item">9</div>
</div>
```